# Can not execute Test cases of a specific class from ADB command in android project

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, nunit, adb

I am having Xamarin.Android unit test project. I am executing test cases from adb command line as below.

> adb shell am instrument -w -e class Package.Android.Test.MyTestClass
>   Package.Android.Test/app.tests.TestInstrumentation

I am having many test classes, every time all test cases are running from all the classes. I want to run test cases from specific class. Can anyone faced this issue.?

I tried seeing ADB log, it always prints **"[Runner executing:  Run Everything]
"**.

Test cases are written using NUnitlite.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use `NUnit`/`NUnitlite` [Categories](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Category-Attribute) to restrict which tests are run.

In the default `TestSuiteActivity` the following call in the `Activity`'s `OnCreate` sets which tests are run:

```
AndroidRunner.Runner.AddTestFilters (GetIncludedCategories (), GetExcludedCategories ());
```

Both, `GetIncludedCategories` and `GetExcludedCategories` in the default implementation return `null`, so you can subclass `TestSuiteActivity`, override these methods and return the `Categories` that should be run.

I currently do this and pass `Categories` to be run via `extras` (`-e categories Large`) added to the `adb shell am instrument` command.

Ref: [TestSuiteActivity.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/8b0d145b6e9f323148bb86ed7742803502b0090a/src/Xamarin.Android.NUnitLite/Gui/Activities/TestSuiteActivity.cs#L97)

```
protected virtual IEnumerable <string> GetIncludedCategories ()
{
    return null;
}

protected virtual IEnumerable <string> GetExcludedCategories ()
{
    return null;
}
```